# Android - ListView with Spinner - cannot select the list item (as a whole)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

In a ListView each row contains 1 textview and 1 spinner. 
The spinner works fine.

How can I select the complete list row? So, click on it and do some action?

I tried both m_listview.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() { ... and registering a longclick/context menu. 
On clicking / longclicking ... these methods / listeners are never called.

A similar question was solved by putting "android:focusable="false" and       android:focusableInTouchMode="false"" for the button. 
The button works, the list item (row) can be selected. Great. 
This solution does not work for a list row with a spinner in it.

So, I replaced the spinner with a button, again added the "focusable=false". It then works fine for the button. Changing it back to a spinner, nope, the row cannot be selected.

On request the most relevant parts of the code:

1 - the rowlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/variable_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text=""
      android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
      android:textSize="12sp" />

     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/variable_use_answer"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:entries="@array/variables_use_answers_short"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
 etc.
```

2 - the fragment with the list and other textviews and buttons:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/variables_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/variables_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/waypoint_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="Action A" />
   etc.
```

3 - most important part of the adapter code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View concertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (concertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.waypoint_rowlayout, parent, false);
    } else { 
        view = (LinearLayout) concertView;
    }
    variableV = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.variable_name);
    useAnswerV = (Spinner) view.findViewById( R.id.variable_use_answer);
    useAnswerV.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println( "Item: " + parent.getItemAtPosition( position).toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { };
    }); 
    return view;
}
```

4 - the fragment code (surrounding code)

```
onCreateView 
    ... 
    m_listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.variable_list);
    ... 
    adapter = new VariableAdapter( getActivity(), varList);
    m_listview.setAdapter( adapter);
    m_listview.invalidateViews();
    ....
    m_listview.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
             // -----> N*E*V*E*R   C*O*M*I*N*G H*E*R*E* <----------- 
             VariableInfo var = (VariableInfo) m_listview.getAdapter().getItem( position);
             System.out.println( "Variable clicked on: " + var );
    });
```

Comment: Post some code so we can get an idea of what the problem can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the rowlayout

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
android:focusable=false
android:focusableInTouchMode=false
```

for your all custom UI of ListView Row.

Comment: I've done this, but this does NOT help for a Spinner.